# A symmetric inequality

Tags: inequality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and three-letter identities (exercise 1.4 from “The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class”)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71509/cauchy-schwarz-inequality-and-three-letter-identities-exercise-1-4-from-the-ca)

Is it true for all $x, y, z > 0$ that

$$ x + y + z \leq 2 \left\{ \frac{x^2}{y+z} + \frac{y^2}{x+z} + \frac{z^2}{x+y} \right\} $$

This is an exercise (1.4) in "The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class: An Introduction to the Art of mathematical Inequalities"

The solution suggests applying C-S to
$$ x + y + z = \frac{x}{\sqrt{y+z}}\sqrt{y+z} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x+z}}\sqrt{x+z}
+ \frac{z}{\sqrt{x+y}}\sqrt{x+y} $$

Comment: This is basically the same question as [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and three-letter identities (exercise 1.4 from *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class*)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71509/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct  $ x + y + z = \frac{x}{\sqrt{y+z}}\sqrt{y+z} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x+z}}\sqrt{x+z}
+ \frac{z}{\sqrt{x+y}}\sqrt{x+y}\le \left(\frac{x^2}{y+z}+\frac{y^2}{x+z}+\frac{z^2}{y+x}\right)^{1/2}(2x+2y+2z)^{1/2}.$ Square both sides, and cancel out $x+y+z$.

Comment: How embarrassing.  Yes.

Comment: No embarrassing. I make silly mistakes often...